# Adding firebase to JavaFX on windows

Tags: java, windows, firebase, intellij-idea, firebase-authentication

I know this is might be a noob question but that is what I am xD.

I'm trying to add Firebase to a Java application I'm doing for windows but in their documentation they say I have to add id to the build.gradel or Maven but I don't have neither on my folder.

the only thing I have is a gradle.xml

[image: folder]

and the code in there is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4" >

  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="gradleHome" value="C:/Program Files (x86)/Gradle/gradle-1.0-rc-3" />

  </component>
</project>
```

What should I do and can I do it?

Thanks :D

Comment: Easiest and simplest solution is that you create a Gradle or Maven-based project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add Maven Framework Support

[image]

[image]

and then you can follow firabase instructions.

Be careful.
It seems to not support JDK 10, if you use JDK 8 it works.